# Media Query - page width expands when at 640px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having trouble with the breakpoint at 640px. For some reason the page width enlarges when it breaks at 640px and makes a huge gap to the right, almost like there is a margine there. By the look of it the problem lyes with the logo size. The browser thinks it is wider than it really is. Hopfully the code can clear it up for you so you can see what im talking about...

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Webbit Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div id="logo" class="grid_4">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/webbit-logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div id="nav" class="grid_8 omega">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="detail"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="work"><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="intro-home" class="grid_12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Bblah blah.  <p></p>
        </div>



        <div id="copyright" class="grid_12">
            <p>© Webbit Design. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

/*global*/

body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 3em 6.5em;
}

a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #50B748;
}



/*typography*/

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    margin: 0;
}
}
h3 {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    color: #444;
}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}



/*navigation*/
#logo {
    margin: 5% 0 1% 38.6%;

}


#nav {
    margin-left: 34%
}
#nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8% 0 30 90;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    }
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    }
    #nav ul li.home {
        width: 15%;
    }
    #nav ul li.detail {
        width: 15%;
    }
    #nav ul li.work {
        width: 15%;
    }
    #nav ul li.contact {
        width: 15%;

    }

    }
#nav ul li a {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav ul li a:hover {
color: #50B748;
    }

/*content*/

p .quote{
    font-style: italic;
}

img .quote-close{
    margin-left: 50px;
}


}
#new-work {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

#new-work img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 0 0% 0;
}


#featured-work {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
#featured-work img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 0 0% 0;
}
#contact {
    margin-top: 2%;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#contact span{

    color: #50B748;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding: 2% 0;
    margin: 2% 0;
    margin-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Form */
#form {
    width: 90%;

    background: #EEE;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
    color: #444;
    border:1px solid #DADADA;
}

}
#form h1>span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#form label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
}
#form label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #888;
}
#form input[type="text"], #form input[type="email"], #form textarea,#form select{
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #888;
    height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 70%;

}

#form textarea{
    height:100px;
}
#form .button {
    background: #50B748;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#form .button:hover {
    background: #444
}

/*Work*/

.work-img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;

}

.line {

}

/*media queries*/

/* Tablet ----------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

.container {
    margin-right: 0;
}

#intro {
    width: 100%; 
}

#intro h1 {
    margin:  0 0 0% 0;

}
#logo img {
margin-left: -16%;
margin-bottom: -15%;
}

#nav ul {
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5% 0 0 -2.5%;
    }
    #nav ul li.home {
        width: %;
    }
    #nav ul li.detail {
        width: %;
    }
    #nav ul li.work {
        width: %;
    }
    #nav ul li.contact {
        width: %;
    }


}


/* Small ----------- */
@media screen and (max-width : 640px) {

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
    width:100%;
}

.container {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#logo img {
max-width: 100%;
margin-right: 0;
}
#nav ul {
    font-size: 1.2em;

}

#nav ul li a {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font-size: 0.750em;
}

#nav ul li {


    }
    #nav ul  li.home {
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #nav ul  li.detail {
        width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #nav ul  li.work {
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #nav ul  li.contact {
        width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    }


#featured-work, #new-work {
    margin: 5% 0;
}

h1 {
    line-height: 0.7em;
}
```

The other break point seems to be fine!
Thanks

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on your media query. Not sure if that will resolve your problem or not, but you should fix that.

Comment: Still a big gap to the right..

Comment: Can you share grid.css/style.css?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to my comment above, this is what the media query should look like:

```
/* Small ----------- */
@media screen and (max-width : 640px) {

    .grid_1,
    .grid_2,
    .grid_3,
    .grid_4,
    .grid_5,
    .grid_6,
    .grid_7,
    .grid_8,
    .grid_9,
    .grid_10,
    .grid_11,
    .grid_12 {
        width:100%;
    }

    .container {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    #logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
    #nav ul {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        font-size: 0.750em;
    }

    #nav ul li {

    }
        #nav ul  li.home {
            width: 10%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #nav ul  li.detail {
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #nav ul  li.work {
            width: 10%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #nav ul  li.contact {
            width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
        }


    #featured-work, #new-work {
        margin: 5% 0;
    }

    h1 {
        line-height: 0.7em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logo has the class `.grid_4`, and the navbar has the class `.grid_8`, which means that at your 640px breakpoint their width is set to `100%`. Coupled with their margins that will make those elements extend outside their parent container.

To fix this you'll need to override the rule that is setting their `width` to `100%`. In your 640px media query add:

```
#logo, #nav {
    width: auto;
}
```